# Jest and jquery-i18next without using react

Tags: javascript, internationalization, jestjs, i18next

I really need some help figuring out why ' .localize() ' will not work with my Jest testing suite. Across various tests, I always get a non-passing test result because apparently
"$(...).localize is not a function".

My jestSetup file has global.localize = jest.fn();

What seems to be the issue is that I'll have something like this:

```
it('should update with the right animal', () => {
  document.body.innerHTML =
   `<div class='hopScotch'></div>`
  superFunctionMango('OWL')

  expect($('.hopScotch').attr('data- 
   i18n')).toBe('OWL.#')

//and it allpasses except for app.localize

})
```

superFunctionMango looks like this in the actual js file:

```
function updateNewInvoiceFieldsWithCorrectDocType(bird) {
$("#newBarBird").attr("data-i18n", `${bird}.new`);
$(".newBirdTitle").attr("data-i18n", 
  `${bird}.#`);
$(".newBirdDate").attr("data-i18n", 
  `${bird}.date`);
$(".newBirdSelect").attr("data-i18n", `${bird}.name`);
$("#app").localize();
```

}

It's that $('#app').localize() that always seems to mess things up. Wat do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.fn.extend({
 localize: jest.fn(),
 language: jest.fn(),
 i18n:{
 changeLanguage: jest.fn()
 }

});
```

Figured it out, simple really. All you have to do is extend jQuery's methods in the setupJest.js!! :)